# References to Aspirin in the "Chicago" musical

Tags: 20th-century, 1920s

In the musical "[Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(musical))", in the song "[All That Jazz](https://www.allmusicals.com/lyrics/chicago/overtureallthatjazz.htm)", there are references to Aspirin that I don't understand.  I was hoping that someone would be able to provide some historical context.

The specific lines are:

> **Velma:** Hold on, hon
>   We're gonna bunny hug
>   I bought some Aspirin
>   Down at United Drug
>
> In case you shake apart
>   And want a brand-new start
>   To do that -
>
> **Velma & Company:** Jazz!

The most I've been able to find from searching google is information about the "[Chicago Tylenol Murders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Tylenol_murders)", but this doesn't seem to fit the timeline of the musical, nor the context of the song.

Comment: really interesting question.  It was fun to research it and fun to read the answers.  Good Job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The word "aspirin" for long was used as an euphemism for "condoms".

To speak about condoms was considered indecent. They were sold at the same place - drugstore, and in small paper packages, as aspirin. So, the word "aspirin" started to be used as an euphemism.

There was even an old anecdote about it:

> An interview in the television study for a position of an announcer.
>
> A guy with tic comes. He winks incessantly.
>
> Everything is excellent, but they say:
>
> -- Sorry, your tic could be a problem.
>
> -- Oh, it is not a problem, one aspirin an I am OK.
>
> The guy looks in pockets, pulls out several heaps of condoms, at last finds a  package of aspirin, swallows it the tic stops and he  passes all remaining tests.
>
> -- You are fine, but we are a decent company and don't want to take such sexual aggressor.
>
> -- You mean these condoms? Try to ask for an aspirin in a drugstore and wink!

Comment: Interesting!  What is the source of the anecdote?

Comment: I have read it as an example of English humour when I studied English in about 1976. The book was taken in a library and was not new already. Apparently, it was published in relatively free years of 65-67. To get into Russian editions of English textbooks also took much time. So, the anecdote should be definitely more than ten years old then.

Comment: This, combined with "Bunny Hug" being the name of a dance that is supposed to resemble rabbits having sex, makes a fairly convincing argument.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found..  Aspirin seems to be the lyric which best translates into the 21st century

> [Slang City](http://www.slangcity.com/songs/all_that_jazz.htm)
>   **Hold on, hon**
>   **We're gonna bunny hug**
>   *bunny hug Thanks to reader Jim P., who writes "That actually refers to a dance popular in the 1920s called the Bunny Hug which apparently was meant to simulate rabbits having sex." I'd like to see that! Or maybe not...

[Bunny Hug Video](https://youtu.be/VpfSx9zwAIQ?list=PLWpw6jkCaiTDcHq-b1WKP2_8Mm-WAJngk&t=188)

.

> [Slang City](http://www.slangcity.com/songs/all_that_jazz.htm)
>   **I bought some aspirin down at United Drug**
>   in anticipation of tomorrow's hangover
>
> **In case you shake apart
>
>   And want a brand-new start
>
>   To do that -**

[Shimmy shake dance](https://youtu.be/IcemYjTdvZ8) by wiggling the body from side to side

That's pretty much how I dance now.

Comment: I'm now wondering the shimmy shake dance referenced is related directly to aspirin's potential side effect of causing shaking with high doses.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  That does fit too with -  "and want a brand-new start"..  In fact the more I think of it the better it fits, over hang over.

Comment: Later in the song, the line "lucky Lindy never flew so high" is talking about getting high, most likely from cocaine, which was very trendy at the time, I wonder if it could also be a reference to the urban legend that combining cocaine and aspirin resulted in an even better high.